# php script isn't passing value correctly or isn't querying from mysql correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, get

I have a two php sripts - one being the main page (*index.php*) and the other (*refresh.php*) getting the info from a mysql table and displaying it.

In *index.php* after having established a connection to the mysql database I query to get an *id* to pass to *refresh.php*:

```html
<?php 
  $stagequery = "SELECT stage FROM teams WHERE team_name = '$team_name'";
  $stageresult = mysql_query($stagequery) or die('Error, couldnt find a clue to   display'.mysql_error()); 
  $stagerow = mysql_fetch_assoc($stageresult);
  $id = $stagerow['stage'];
?>
<iframe method="get" id="dynamic-content" src="refresh.php?id=$id"  />
```

Then in *refresh.php* I do the following with the id:

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];  
    echo $_GET['id'];
    //*Connect to database here*
    $query = "SELECT clue FROM clues WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error find a clue to table'.mysql_error()); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['clue'];
    echo "test";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The box, where this is all supposed to display, shows $id (from `echo $_GET['id']`) and the it displays test as well. I don't understand **how come the value of id is not getting passed into the script** (I tried hardcoding the value of $id in *index.php*, but that didn't work either).

Comment: $query = "SELECT clue FROM clues WHERE id='$id'"; this is suicidal

Comment: is it bad style? well i guess i can see it not being the best way of naming/doing things, but this is only a prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit.

```
<iframe method="get" id="dynamic-content" src="refresh.php?id=$id"  />
```

You should use php to echo the `$id` in your html.

```
<iframe method="get" id="dynamic-content" src="refresh.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"  />
```

Otherwise you just post `$id` into the url instead of the value of `$id`

Comment: knew it had to be something simple, thanks a lot :))